# Looping through the last dimension of an array and if an element does not exist add it

Tags: vba, dynamic, multidimensional-array

I am using VBA to get Metadata from an API and create a MetadataArray. I am stuck at the headers. I want to check if the element exists in the array, if not redim the array and add the new element. When I run the code, I get an error

> Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range

at:
 `MetadataArray(0, UBound(MetadataArray, 2) + 1) = AllIndicators(i).ChildNodes(j).BaseName`

```
For k = 0 To UBound(MetadataArray, 2)
    If MetadataArray(0, k) = AllIndicators(i).ChildNodes(j).BaseName Then
    Else
        ReDim Preserve MetadataArray(0 To RowCount, 0 To UBound(MetadataArray, 2) + 1)
        MetadataArray(0, UBound(MetadataArray, 2) + 1) = AllIndicators(i).ChildNodes(j).BaseName
    End If
Next k
```

Comment: Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the it doesn't work as written is that you are asking to set an array element that does not yet exist. You do create a new upper bound to the `MetadataArray` in the previous statement, but in the next statement you are asking to fill the value 1 more than the Upper Bound, which **will never exist**.

So change

```
MetadataArray(0, UBound(MetadataArray, 2) + 1) = AllIndicators(i).ChildNodes(j).BaseName
```

to this:

```
MetadataArray(0, UBound(MetadataArray, 2)) = AllIndicators(i).ChildNodes(j).BaseName
```

as the `UBound` will reflect the new upper bound of the array set in the previous statement.